# Mongoose with typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

I have a project in nodejs and typescript.  I'm using mongoose to connect to a mongoDb database.  My code looks like this

```js
import { Schema, Document, Model } from 'mongoose';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export interface IProblem extends Document {
  problem: string;
  solution: string;
}

const ProblemSchema = new Schema({
  problem: { type: String, required: true },
  solution: { type: String, required: true },
});

export async function findOneByProblem(
  this: IProblemModel,
  { problem, solution }: { problem: string; solution: string }
): Promise<IProblem> {
  const record = await this.findOne({ problem, solution });
  return record;
}

export default mongoose.model('Problem', ProblemSchema);

ProblemSchema.statics.findOneByProblem = findOneByProblem;

export interface IProblemModel extends Model<IProblem> {
  findOneByProblem: (
    this: IProblemModel,
    { problem, solution }: { problem: string; solution: string }
  ) => Promise<IProblem>;
}
```

However, at these lines

```js
const record = await this.findOne({ problem, solution });
return record;
```

I get a compiler error saying this

```
TS2322: Type 'IProblem | null' is not assignable to type 'IProblem'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'IProblem'.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Your type for `findOneByProblem` is wrong – after all, it's possible that you don't  find an `IProblem` instance, and the result is null.

The correct type is

```
Promise<IProblem | null>
```

– or you could internally `if(problem === null) throw new Error("No Problem found");` or similar in the function if you don't want to change the type.